# $K\subset L$ Galois-extension with $Gal(L/K)=G, ord(G)=p^2$ then there are $p+3$ subextensions

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, abelian-groups

> Let $K\subset L$ Galois-extension with $Gal(L/K)=G, ord(G)=p^2,p>0$ prime and $G$ is a **elementary abelian p Group**. Proof there are $p+3$ subextensions $K\subset E\subset L$.

Need some hints.

Comment: Hint: How many subspaces does the 2-dimensional vector space $\Bbb{Z}_p^2$ have? Most of them are 1-dimensional.

Comment: I see, $(p^2-1)/(p-1)=p+1, 1-dim$ Spaces plus the two trivial ones we get $p+3$ subspaces and $G$ is isomorph to $\mathbb Z_p^2$.

Comment: Correct! Good job, Serge! You can also post it as an answer, if so inclined :-)